# how to send param from docker to fluentd to dynamically decide on file output

Tags: docker, fluentd

I want my hello-world container to output to fluentD - and I'd like FluentD to dynamically set it to a folder

The idea is to start container like this

```
docker run --log-driver=fluentd --log-opt fluentdLogsDirName=docker.{{.NAME}} hello-world
```

and the config file of the fluentd is like this

```
<source>
  @type forward
</source>

<match docker.**>
  @type file
  path /var/log/fluentd/#{fluentdLogsDirName}
  time_slice_format %Y%m%d
  time_slice_wait 10m
  time_format %Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z
  compress gzip
  utc
</match>
```

Thing is - fluentD has errors on startup (BTW fluentd also is a docker)

```
2016-03-28 14:48:56 +0000 [info]: reading config file path="/fluentd/etc/test.conf"
2016-03-28 14:48:56 +0000 [info]: starting fluentd-0.12.21
2016-03-28 14:48:56 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '0.12.21'
2016-03-28 14:48:56 +0000 [info]: adding match pattern="docker.**" type="stdout"
2016-03-28 14:48:56 +0000 [info]: adding match pattern="docker.**" type="file"
2016-03-28 14:48:56 +0000 [error]: config error file="/fluentd/etc/test.conf" error="out_file: `/var/log/fluentd/\#{fluentdLogsDirName}.20160328_0.log` is not writable"
2016-03-28 14:48:56 +0000 [info]: process finished code=256
2016-03-28 14:48:56 +0000 [warn]: process died within 1 second. exit.
```

started my fluendd containter:

```
docker run -it -p 24224:24224 -v /blabla:/fluentd/etc -e FLUENTD_CONF=test.conf fluent/fluentd:latest
```

http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/out_file

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `fluentdLogsDirName` currently is an option for the fluentd log-driver in docker; https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/fluentd/

Also, Go templates (`{{ .Name }}`) are only supported for *tags* (https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/log_tags/) and not for other options to logging drivers.

So at this moment, I don't think this is possible